# Use full processing power with perl

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have a perl script which is running correct but it is only using 1 core of my 2 core CPU, how can i make it utilise all cores.

I know that i can create threads using threads->new(); but how do i fit that into something like:

```
my $twig= new XML::Twig::XPath(TwigRoots => {TrdCaptRpt => \&top_level});
$twig->parsefile($file);
```

where the subroutine is being called by something else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard approach with Perl is to not try to use multiple cores with one invocation of the script, but instead to run jobs in parallel on separate cores.

Yes, you can use threading with Perl, but Perl's threading is (very) heavyweight.  To avoid potential race conditions, when you spawn a thread Perl simply copies everything that it does not want to explicitly share.  Therefore using threading is likely to be much slower than not.

Comment: It really depends on the workload.  If it is very cpu bound, and there is a benefit of real shared data beteen the instances, perl's thread model can provide significant speed increases in spite of its overhead.  I've written plenty of programs where perl's threads gave a 300-350% speed boost on a 4 core system.

Comment: I generally agree with the sentiment expressed, as I also suggested in my answer, however this kind of multiprocess parallelism doesn't work as well if the problem is not embarrassingly parallelizable.  If you need a lot of synchronization and communication, I think it's much easier to do in-process. Perl might not be a great answer in that case, but perhaps still better than trying to do it external to the process.

Comment: @eric-strom: There are cases where what you say is true.  But they are more of the exception than the rule.  And in those cases I'd be inclined to go with a language other than Perl.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to modify the code of XML::Twig.  There is no canned answer of what would need to be done.  if you find yourself having to run this script for multiple files, a better and very simple option, is to write your script so it can run for more than 1 file at the same time.  You could do that with threads or you could do that with a wrapper script that executes 2 copies of your script at the same time (perhaps with xargs?).

Comment: @Joel: My understanding is that Coro gives you cooperative multitasking within one thread, it does NOT allow you to take advantage of multiple cores.

Comment: @btilly, I think you may be right, I was just looking at that. Sorry.